# How to use hooks inside a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a state and I want to increase its value based on an if statement :

```
const ChangeQuiz=(e)=>{
 if(e.target.innerHTML === quiz.Correct)
    usePoints(++points);          // I want this to increase its value based on the if statement 
   var toEnd = true;
  useCounter(++counter);
  useQuiz(qizArr[counter]);

 }
```

But its giving me the 'React Hook "usePoints" is called conditionally' message .
So how can I get around that ??

Comment: That's not the correct way of using hooks :) I suggest reading the documentation, the example is exactly what you are trying to do
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: what is `usePoints()`? Is it a custom hook? Can you post the code for that function?

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are called at the root level of a functional component, or by other hooks. Hooks must *never* be called conditionally, or from event handlers. But you can call any function *returned by* the hook at pretty much any point.

I'm not sure what `usePoints()` does exactly, but here is how you would set this up using `useState`

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [points, setPoints] = useState(0)

  function ChangeQuiz(e) {
    if (e.target.innerHTML === quiz.Correct) setPoints(points + 1)
    // other logic
  }

  return <div>
    {/* component JSX here */}
  </div>
}
```

In this example `setPoints()` is called conditionally, which is fine because it is not a hook. It's a function the hook returns.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't see how my code is different from yours!

Comment: My code calls a hook everytime the component renders, and uses a return value of that hook in an event handler. Your code calls a custom hook from an event handler, which is not a valid use of hooks.